# How to determine if User Control is shown or not on WinForms

Tags: c#

I have a windows forms application and added a menu to maneuver between few User Controls. I am using the events: `Click`, `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave`.

In every event I am changing the BackgroudImage and what i want to achieve is that when the image did change after the click event, the image will stay. And I was thinking using the User Control properties to determine if he is Shown or not (as I am using the `Show()` and `Hide()` methods).

Tried using the Visible, Focused and Enabled properties but none of them changing after hiding or showing the User Control.

How can i determine if the User Control is shown or not?

Comment: `.Show()` and `.Hide()` are both [actually only changing](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,12344) the `Visible` property of a control. If it doesn't change you are doing something else to the controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently when the form loaded, the default Visible property is set to True even though I really don’t see all of the User Controls (they are one on each other). 
So I added a show and hide method in the form load event and the visible property works like a Charm. 
Thank Franck

Answer (score 2):

The property **IsHandleCreated** gets true when the control is loaded. Try to use this property.

reference document  :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.ishandlecreated?view=netframework-4.7.2